# Not removing other rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason it only removes the first row and not sure why.

```
function templatesArray(whatsThis) {
    var myNewArray = new Array(); 
    var aRow = new Array();

    $('input:checkbox[name="templates"]:checked').each(function(i) { 
        myNewArray.push($(this).val());
        aRow.push(oTable.fnGetPosition( $(this).parents('tr').get(0)));
    }); 
    var dataString = 'templatesArray=' + myNewArray + '&deleteTemplatesArray=True'; 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "processes/templates.php", 
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.errorsExist) {
            } else {
                $(whatsThis).parents("tr").eq(0).hide(); 
                for (i in aRow)  // loop over the array of row indexes
                  oTable.fnDeleteRow(aRow[i]);
                if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() == 0) {
                    $('.bt_red').remove();
                    $('.bt_blue').remove();
                }
                if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() <= 10) {
                    $('.bt_blue').remove();
                }
                if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() <= 10) {
                    $('div.pagination').remove();
                }
            } 
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What is oTable? Where's the markup? You need to be more verbose than a 1 liner and some code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/3Ldj5/   Its supposed to perform the server side action which it DOES and then remove the row from the table but was only doing the first one in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `for .. in` on Arrays.  You can get unexpected results.  Instead use `Array.foreach` or jQuery's `$.each()`:

```
$.each(aRow, function() {
    oTable.fnDeleteRow(this);
});
```

If that doesn't fix it, please post more details, such as the code for `oTable.fnDeleteRow()`.  Are any JavaScript errors being thrown?

**Edit:**  Your code is passing the row index to the delete function.  After the delete function is called all proceeding rows have a new row index.  So if you try to delete rows 1, 2, and 3, you'll end up deleting rows 1, 3, and 5.  Instead store and pass a reference to the row itself:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="templates"]:checked').each(function(i) { 
    myNewArray.push($(this).val());
    aRow.push($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ldj5/2/

Comment: I've included a copy of it in a jsfiddle.   http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/3Ldj5/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are selecting the aRow index incorreclt just a guess
if the purpose of this (in your "checked" loop)

```
$(this).parents('tr').get(0)
```

is to select a row try:

```
$(this).closest('tr')
```

and in your ajax success callback instead

```
 $(whatsThis).parents("tr").eq(0).hide();
```

try

```
 $(whatsThis).closest("tr").hide();
```